# Windows phone 8.1 flip view issue

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, flipview

I am working on a gallery app where i need show the images on Flipview. When in Flipview, i would like to zoom in/out of the image. Here's my code where i am trying to display an image and performing a composite transform on it.

```
<Image Source="Assets/WP_20150914_11_30_50_Pro.jpg"
                Stretch="Uniform"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
                ManipulationDelta="img_intro_ManipulationDelta"
                ManipulationMode="All">
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform/>
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>

private void img_intro_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Image img = sender as Image;

            CompositeTransform ct = img.RenderTransform as CompositeTransform;

            ct.ScaleX *= e.Delta.Scale;
            ct.ScaleY *= e.Delta.Scale;

            if (ct.ScaleX < 1.0) ct.ScaleX = 1.0;
            if (ct.ScaleY < 1.0) ct.ScaleY = 1.0;
            if (ct.ScaleX > 4.0) ct.ScaleX = 4.0;
            if (ct.ScaleY > 4.0) ct.ScaleY = 4.0;

            ct.TranslateX += e.Delta.Translation.X;
            ct.TranslateY += e.Delta.Translation.Y;

            if (ct.TranslateY > (((img.ActualHeight * ct.ScaleY) - img.ActualHeight) / 2))
            {
                ct.TranslateY = (((img.ActualHeight * ct.ScaleY) - img.ActualHeight) / 2);
            }

            if (ct.TranslateY < 0 - ((((img.ActualHeight * ct.ScaleY) - img.ActualHeight)) / 2))
            {
                ct.TranslateY = 0 - ((((img.ActualHeight * ct.ScaleY) - img.ActualHeight)) / 2);
            }

            if (ct.TranslateX > (((img.ActualWidth * ct.ScaleX) - img.ActualWidth) / 2))
            {
                ct.TranslateX = (((img.ActualWidth * ct.ScaleX) - img.ActualWidth) / 2);
            }

            if (ct.TranslateX < 0 - ((((img.ActualWidth * ct.ScaleX) - img.ActualWidth)) / 2))
            {
                ct.TranslateX = 0 - ((((img.ActualWidth * ct.ScaleX) - img.ActualWidth)) / 2);
            }             
        }
```

This works well without a Flipview. But when i add it to a flipview i won't be able to flip to the next item or previous item.

Any suggestions how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than making use of manipulation delta put the image inside a scrollviewer, as it wont fire an event every time for manipulation to occur on the ui thread.

try some thing like

```
<Flipview>
<ScrollViewer MaxZoomFactor="4">
<Image>
</Image>
</Scrollviewer>
</Flipview>
```

Since m not having an IDE currently this is the best possible help, give a try and let me know.

Comment: Tried this. It does not give a native gallery zoom effect. Also, there are many issues related like if the image is clicked in a landscape mode then while zooming the same in portrait mode will push the picture to the left top.

Comment: try putting the flipview in a scrollviewer, let the flipview increase in size when zoomed. ull get the slide effect also. suggestion

Comment: Doesn't work. The problem with flipview is that, if we set the ManipulationMode to anything in the Image, then the flipView doesn't let us slide to the next image. Have the Flipview inside the scroll viewer does not help this situation.

Comment: whats the height and width of the flipview ur using ?

Comment: Height and Width are not set. Its Auto.

Comment: put the image inside a grid and hardcode the height and width of the grid and then try flipping to next image, let the manipulation remain on the Image.